# How to read the input from the user which is iterating over array

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, angular-ngmodel

I have a list which is iterating over array in which there is a input tag how to read the values from the text box after clicking on button where the input box are generated from the length of the list

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let arrayitems of arrayElements">
    <P>{{arrayitems}}</P>
    <input type ="text" placeholder="{{arrayitems}}">
  </div>
  <button (click)="submitFunction()" style="margin-top:10px">CLICK ME!</button>
</div>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
 arrayElements : any;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.arrayElements=["listElementOne","listElementTwo","listElementThree","listElementFour","listElementFive","listElementSix"];
  }
  submitFunction(){
    alert("Function Called");
    console.log("print all the values taken from the input tag");

  }
```

Stack Blitz Link [link to edit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-tag-iterating-over-array)

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958114/angular2-reactive-form-containing-a-list

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview. I downvoted because I think you has not read any docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the values in a seperate array, then use ngModel to bind the values.

Following is the updated app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  arrayElements : any;

  items: string[] = [];

  ngOnInit(){
    this.arrayElements=["listElementOne","listElementTwo","listElementThree","listElementFour","listElementFive","listElementSix"];
  }
  submitFunction(){
    console.log(this.items);
  }
}
```

and app.component.html

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let arrayitems of arrayElements;let i = index;">
    <P>{{arrayitems}}</P>
    <input type ="text" [(ngModel)]="items[i]" placeholder="{{arrayitems}}">
  </div>
  <button (click)="submitFunction()" style="margin-top:10px">CLICK ME!</button>
</div>
```

I've also updated your code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-tag-iterating-over-array-2fezah

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not angular way of doing this, you can use `ElemenRef` to query all inputs.

```js
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { }

submitFunction() {
  const list: NodeList = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("input");

  list.forEach((el: HTMLInputElement, idx) => {
    console.log(`el${idx}: ${el.value}`);
  });
}
```

here is a working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-tag-iterating-over-array-pfovrj)

but you should definitely take a look at [ReactiveForms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us a bit more information here, what is the response that you are getting at

```
<P>{{arrayitems}}</P>.
```

i'm guessing its undifined?

Comment: on the ngOnInit(){this.arrayElements=["listElementOne","listElementTwo","listElementThree","listElementFour","listElementFive","listElementSix"]} i am defining a list please look on to the code

Answer (score 0):

Assign unique ids to each input field.

```
<input type ="text" id={{arrayitems}} placeholder="{{arrayitems}}">
```

In submit function find elements by id and read their contents from the "value" property.

```
for (const elementId of this.arrayElements) {
    const element = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(elementId)
    const content = element.value
    console.log(content)
}
```

Seems to work, though I have no idea what that "arrayItems" syntax is in app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the app.component.html where I add a new change method for the input field.

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let arrayitems of arrayElements">
    <P>{{arrayitems}}</P>
    <input type ="text" (change)="inputChange($event, arrayitems)" 
           placeholder="{{arrayitems}}">
  </div>
  <button (click)="submitFunction()" style="margin-top:10px">CLICK ME! 
  </button>
</div>
```

In app.component.ts we can define a the input change method which will assign the input value to the result where the key is the element name. In submit method we filter the result and return a list o results.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  arrayElements : any;
  result = {};

  ngOnInit(){
    this.arrayElements= ["listElementOne","listElementTwo","listElementThree","listElementFour","listElementFive","listElementSix"];
  }
  inputChange(e, itemName) {
    this.result[itemName] = e.target.value
  }
   submitFunction(){
    const submitResult = this.arrayElements.map(element => {
      if (this.result[element]) {
        return this.result[element];
      }
    })
    .filter(e => !!e)

    console.log(submitResult)
    alert("Function Called");
  }
}
```

Hopefully it helps you!